# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable - Trying To Create A Graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphing

I'm trying to create a simple program where my inputs about data relating to daily COVID-19 cases will then be tabulated and created into a small graph. For example, I'll first input (primary input) will be: 7 20200401 20200403, which represents the # of inputs after my primary input, and from what dates the cases are from. Then I'll go onto input which the hospital, the # of cases from that hospital, and the day of the report. The number of cases per day will be represented by a * . When I go to run my program, I'm being met with a:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/-/-/-/-.py", line 25, in

print("{}{}{}".format(EmptySet[i], ":", "*" * CaseNumberList [i]))

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Is there any way to fix it, and have the program properly display the correct amount of cases per day?

Here is my code:

```
CoronaCaseNumber = input("")
CoronaList = CoronaCaseNumber.split(" ")
LuckyNumber = CoronaList[0]
Date = CoronaList[1]
Date2 = CoronaList[2]
LuckyNumero = int(LuckyNumber)
DateList = []
CaseNumberList = []
for case in range(LuckyNumero):
    CoronaCaseData = input()
    CoronaList2 = CoronaCaseData.split(" ")
    InfoDate = CoronaList2[1]
    DateList.append(InfoDate)
    CaseNumber = CoronaList2[2]
    CaseNumberList.append(CaseNumber)

EmptySet = []
for i in DateList:
    if i >= Date and i <= Date2:
        if i not in EmptySet:
            EmptySet.append(i)
IntCaseNumberList = int("".join(str(i) for i in CaseNumberList))
EmptySet.sort()
for i in range(len(EmptySet)):
    print("{}{}{}".format(EmptySet[i], ":", "*" * IntCaseNumberList[i]))
```

Any help is appreciated in this.

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to add the full error traceback message.

Comment: `intCaseNumberList` is an `int`, not a list of `int`. What do you expect `IntCaseNumberList[i]` to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is creating a single integer that's the concatenation of all the numbers in `CaseNumberList`, not a list of integers:

```
IntCaseNumberList = int("".join(str(i) for i in CaseNumberList))
```

So when you try to ue `IntCaseNumberList[i]`, it doesn't work because it's a number, not a list.

To create a list of integers, you need to call `int()` inside in a list comprehension:

```
IntCaseNumberList = [int(i) for i in CaseNumberList]
```

You could also just put integers directly into `CaseNumberList` in the first place, then you wouldn't need to make a new list. Change

```
CaseNumberList.append(CaseNumber)
```

to

```
CaseNumberList.append(int(CaseNumber))
```